# C# - Can I Data Bind between a value and an expression?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, .net-2.0

I have a List and a Button. When the Lists Count == 0, I would like the button Visibility to = false.

How do I do this using Data Binding?

Thanks in advance,

**Added**
I have asked this so that I can try to avoid checking the Count on the list in code every time I add or remove an item to or from the list. But if there is no solution then I will continue to do it that way.

Comment: presumably we are talking Winforms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) that exposes all your data that you intend to bind to UI elements. Create a property in the DTO (with an appropriate name):

```
public bool ButtonVisible
{
   get { return myListCount != 0; }
}
```

Add a `BindingSource` to your form and set it's `DataSource` to your DTO type.

Click on the Button, goto **Properties**. Expand the **DataBindings** node, and click **Advanced**.

Scroll down the list in the left hand pane, and select Visible. Set it's binding to your property exposed vis the BindingSource..

Comment: I don't think that your answer addresses the question completely - it only partially answers what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

**The General Answer**

Write an event handler and register it with your list-control's bindings object

**A Specific Example**

```
class MyForm : Form {
protected Button myButton;
BindingSource myBindingSource;
DataGridView dgv;

public MyForm(List someList) {
    myBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    dgv = new DataGridView();
    this.myButton = new Button();
    this.Controls.Add(myButton);
    this.Controls.Add(dgv);

    myBindingSource.DataSource = someList;
    dgv.DataSource = myBindingSource;

    dgv.DataSource.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler (ListEmptyDisableButton);
}

protected void ListEmptyDisableButton (object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) {
    this.myButton.Visible = this.dgv.RowCount <= 0 ? false : true;          
}
```

}

*PS - I'd vote down the favorite answer. A Data Transfer Object (DTO) misses the whole point and functionality of .NET Binding architechture*

Answer (score 0):

As the question is currently worded, it doesn't sound like it has anything to do w/ DataBind.

If we have a list -- doesn't matter whether it's populated via code or bound to a data source -- we can set the button's visibility based on the count. 
e.g.

```
List<string> somelist = new List<string>();
somelist.Add("string1");
somelist.Add("string2");
Button1.Visible = somelist.Count > 0 ? true : false;
```

Comment: I don't want to do Button1.Visible = somelist.Count > 0 ? true : false; every time I add or remove something to / from the list.

Comment: If it's achievable how I've asked then it would be much neater.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to be using the CurrencyManager and the BindingContext of the control.

http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html#CurrencyManager