# C# How to implement a form which controls are dependant of some properties?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application, different controls are only used dependent of the values of properties from a particular object. The forms constructor accept this object as a parameter.

The form has always some basic functionality, no matter what properties are set of the particular object.

Now I have something like this:

```
if(myObject.SomeProperty)
{
  myControl.Visible = true;
  myOtherControl.Visible = false;
  // and so on
}
```

At this time, the controls that are dependant of `SomeProperty` are buttons and tab items. However, I can imagine that in the future other controls are added to the form and are also dependant of `SomeProperty`.

As you might guess, I want to set this up the right way. But I don't know exactly how. How would you implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways I can think of solving this, depending on your situation you could select the best suited to you.
 1. Databinding is one elegant solution when managing the state (visibilit or other properties) of multiple control's depend on a different object. Additional details in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188611/c-can-i-data-bind-between-a-value-and-an-expression) 
 2. You could write different functions if the combination of the states is only limited to couple of cases to at most 4-5 cases. That ways you can still reason about the methods which set the state depending on the object you are depending on. Ex: Basic_Editing, Advaced_Editing, Custom_Editiong etc. 
 3. If the number of cases are limited you could create multiple forms (User controls) and load them on demand based on the state of the dependent property (or object you are talking about).

> Just having a bunch of if else's makes your code harder to maintain, or comprehend, logically group the states so that 1. You could reason about it later, 2.Someone else understands the reason/logic 3.When there is a change required it can be localized to one of these modular methods (techniques) reducing the time to fix, and test.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this in form constructor:

```
myControl.Visible = myObject.SomeProperty && !myObject.SomeOtherProperty;
myOtherControl.Visible = !myObject.SomeProperty;
....
```

Is it the less code and its rapidly changing.

**OR**

You can create separate functions that will generate controls dynamically at runtime for each form view based on object properties.

Answer (score -1):

First i can see you are setting visibility on/off it means you have already controls on the form every time.. , so that not a good practice, instead create controls only when needed.

As for your scenario you can have an `function` like `Initialize()`  which contains all the code for checking if showing a particular control should be shown or not and then create it and add it to Forms control collection. If any new control come to be added later you have one function to update.

*A more precise answer can be given if you can provide more detail to you scenario*